Failing to retrieve stCORE token on openex app address
I'm sorry the question is for core Blockchain. I staked my core on Staking liquid core(stCORE) l then accidentally send the stCORE without conversion to my openex address. The problem is I'm failing to retrieve the token, but in actual fact I'm seeing the token balance on explorer (scan.coredao.org)

I hope you can retrieve it, but I'm not sure they will see the question here.

Okay! What can I do in order for them to see my question ❓
